# Detect user log on from a Windows Service

Tags: .net, vb.net, popup, authentication

Is there for my .Net application to detect if a user has logged on? It is a Windows Service, so it will be running before logon.

What I want to do is display a "popup" when a user logs on to tell them the status of the application

Comment: Will it work for you to simply have a "popup" application run in the login script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I *think* you can modify the service to allow "Service can interact with desktop" (from services control panel) then create a NotifyIcon in your service which can popup messages on specific events. Though I'm not positive if this is possible, I would google "Windows Service" coupled with "NotifyIcon".

**Addendum**

Take a look at [this SO article on desktop notifications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/535905/windows-service-notifying-user-with-wpf-outlook-style-control-not-becoming-visibl). They go over the cautions of doing so, and way of making this happen (which basically eludes to building a separate application that establishes a perpetual connection that can receive updates from the service and notify accordingly).

Comment: I think he wants to display the popup on each user's monitor when the user logs in.

Comment: @JohnSaunders: Either way, judging by the wording, it sounds like it's a windows service that's either hosting or connecting to a WCF, and once a connection is made notify the user. I still feel what I've provided is the solution to the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [ServiceBase.OnSessionChange](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.serviceprocess.servicebase.onsessionchange.aspx).

Remember to set [CanHandleSessionChangeEvent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.serviceprocess.servicebase.canhandlesessionchangeevent.aspx) to true at the constructor.  Otherwise, this won't take effect.